# Converting/using Makefile in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-creator

I'm trying to build minizip from zlib to build inside of Qt as the rest of the project has been created inside of Qt. How can I port the makefile below into Qt.

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS=-O -I../.. -DHAVE_AES

UNZ_OBJS = miniunz.o unzip.o ioapi.o ../../libz.a libaes.a

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c

all: miniunz

libaes.a:
    cd aes; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)

miniunz:  $(UNZ_OBJS) libaes.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(UNZ_OBJS)
```

Comment: What do you mean "port into Qt"? Qt isn't a build tool. Do you mean QMake? Do you mean your IDE? Do you just mean how do you use the library this makefile builds in your Qt project?

Comment: In case you may not know about this, QT has its own build tool called qmake so add the above in qmake file ( the syntax might be a bit different though).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, @EtanReisner , I'd like to be able to compile the source code that the makefile builds, so that I can add the source code/edited into my project and then successfully build my Qt project.

Comment: Compile that using *what*? QMake? Your IDE? By hand? That's not a complicated makefile. What it runs should be fairly easy to reason out (and easier to empirically test). So if your question is just what commands do you need to add to your build script/setup/etc. to compile it that should tell you that. But I still don't know what you are actually asking for.

Comment: Sorry I'm not being very clear, I have a current project inside of Qt Creator and I using this to Develop and build with. I'm looking to add some additional functionality inside the project and found the zlib (minizip) has the functionality I need. I've added the relevant files to the project from minizip and now through editing the .pro file need to make my project interact with the new functionalities provided by minizip. So just to double check do I just need to add the functionality above into the .pro file ? and what needs to be in the .pro (sorry  I haven't dealt with makefiles before.)

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple: copy all the sources and headers to somewhere in your project tree, then add them to your project in Qt Creator. Finally, add the following line manually to the `.pro` file:

```
DEFINES += HAVE_AES
```